# serverless architecture how it works based on what criteria

Tags: linux, serverless

can anyone tell me how the serverless architecture works
and some people are saying this is the next technology? and is this help for Linux administration?

Answer (score 1):

Serverless is a technology that you can use to create infrastructure as code to work with your cloud provider. An example would be if your company uses Amazon Web Services and you need to create a lambda function. You can do this via serverless and include several infrastructure properties such a virtual private cloud, which IAM roles to use, creating an s3 bucket, having your lambda listen to sns topics, deploying on multiple environments.

Currently our company uses Amazon Web Services in combination with the Hashicorp Stack, (Terraform, Vault, etc.), as well as serverless to create our IAC quickly.

As far as this being the next technology, I can say that maybe not serverless, but infrastructure as code is extremely powerful, reusable, fast failing, and useful.

An example could be you your work place has a production environment and a dev environment. You can deploy the same serverless project to dev and production and if you interpolate the values properly you have a serverless project that can be deployed on any of your environments.

Is technology helpful for a linux admin? I cannot attest to this as I have only used Serverless interactions with cloud providers. I believe that is what Serverless was created for.